# Find the duplicate number in an array

Tags: java

I am trying to find the duplicate number in an array, but it's not working.

```
public class FindDuplicateNumber {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr={10,20,30,40,40,25};

        int[] duplicate=duplicateNumber(arr);

        for(int dup : duplicate ){
            System.out.println("duplicate elements are:\t"+ dup);
        }
    }

    public static int[] duplicateNumber(int[] arr){
        int[] duplicate = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
           if(arr[i]==arr[++i]){
                duplicate[i]= arr[i];
            }
        }
        return duplicate;
    }
}
```

Comment: "but its not working." How so? We can't read your mind.

Comment: Also, by the looks of your code, you might benefit by stepping away from your computer, pulling out a pencil and some paper, and figuring out how *you*, as a human, would find a duplicate number without using a computer. What steps would you take? How might you translate that to instructions that you would give to another person? How might you translate those instructions to pseudocode? And how might you translate that pseudocode to Java?

Comment: Two approaches:  1) An N-squared algorithm that takes each element and searches the remainder of the array for it.  2) Sort the array (generally N-log-N) and look for identical adjacent pairs.

Comment: iam getting duplicate array as 0. when I tried to debug it I can see that controller is not going inside the if condtion. can any one help me out.

Comment: Not sure if this would cause a problem or not, but you really shouldn't use the same exact variable names inside `main` and also your `duplicateNumber` method. Might get confusing.

Comment: What happened when you used the debugger to inspect the values that were being compared in the `if` statement? Did you notice any values being skipped? Are you aware that the `++` operator *changes* `i`?

Answer (score 1):

Never use `++i` or `i++` *inside a loop* unless you really want to skip one of the array (or similar) elements over which you are iterating.

This

```
if(arr[i]==arr[++i]){
```

is not the same as

```
if(arr[i]==arr[i+1]){
```

That said, never use `++i` or `i++` within an expression where also `i` occurs.

**Later**

Another problem you'll soon see is that the array for holding the duplicates is too long. For this, a List is more appropriate.

**Why it does not work**

The additional increment makes the loop skip every other element, so the pair of adjacent values 40 is never compared.

Comment: It would be nice if you give the author some pseudocode because you don't really answer his/her query. Otherwise, this post is just like a comment.

Comment: @bbalchev Well, I'm pointing to the error that's the main reason for missing the pair of adjacent identical values. Basically, the structure of the program is OK (if it really has to find only *adjacent* duplicates.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the algorithm you're using right now.

1. You're using arr[++i] inside of your for loop. Are you aware of what this does? It increments i by 1, which your for loop already does. Hence the i++ at the end. Therefore as you run through your for loop, you are incrementing I twice and skipping half of your array values.
2. You are looping through the array and comparing one value, arr[i], to (I'm assuming what you were trying to do is compare it to the next value, arr[i+1]. Do you see why this wouldn't work, unless the array was sorted? What you need to do is compare each value to every other value in the array which is going to require 2 for loops.

I don't want to just write this code for you because I feel like with these hints you can figure it out. If you need any more help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting is not reasonable to do with primitive arrays.  One reason is that you do not know in advance how large your duplicates array should be.  This type of problem needs to use an array type that is modifiable, such as ArrayList.  Here is a simple version using ArrayList and HashSet.

The `.add()` method for a HashSet returns false if the number has already been added.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FindDuplicateNumber {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr={10,20,30,40,40,25};

        for(Integer dup : duplicateNumber(arr)){
            System.out.println("duplicate elements are:\t"+ dup);
        }
    }

    public static List<Integer> duplicateNumber(int[] arr){

        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        List<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
            if (!set.add(arr[index]))  // false if already in set.
                duplicates.add(arr[index]); 

        return duplicates;
    }
}
```